# Mixing request origins in <audio> stream of 206 ranges causes playback to stop

Tags: javascript, service-worker, audio-streaming, intranet, http-content-range

**TL;DR** When an `<audio>` element receives 206 Content-Range chunks of data, switching the origin of these chunks mid-stream through a service-worker stops the playback, and it cannot be resumed. Why and how can I prevent it from stopping?

---

I have a server on my network and this server knows how to respond to `Content-Range` audio streaming requests with the correct 206 chunks.

On the client, there is an `<audio src="...">` tag and a service-worker that intercepts the fetch requests emitted by that audio element.

- if the service-worker knows that it's on a network outside of that of the server, it will make a "normal request" through the internet to `example.com`
- if the service-worker knows that it's on the same network as the server, it will fetch from a "local URL" `local.example.com` (SSL certificates, signed by certificate authority, and DNS resolution points to a private IP like `192.168.0.4`)

If I leave my home with an audio file currently streaming, here's what happens

- the request made by the service-worker to `local.example.com` fails because the IP is not reachable anymore
- the service-worker can `catch` the error, and start a new request to `example.com`
- the client receives its `Response` from the service-worker as if nothing happened

You can see this happen in the devtools:
[image]
The first request is that of the client, the second (red) the one to `local.example.com`, and the last one the one to `example.com`

Except... that **the audio playback gets interrupted and cannot be resumed**.

To diagnose this issue:

- there is nothing specific on the client, just

  ```html
  <audio src="example.com/api/file/12345678" hidden playsinline autoplay></audio>
  ```
- there is nothing fantastic on the server either. It streams totally fine when reached at `local.example.com` or at `example.com`. The issue only appears when a single `<audio>` is streamed partially from both.
- here's the code from the relevant part of the service worker. As far as I can tell, there isn't much out of the ordinary here, except maybe that the responses are always cloned with `response.clone()` to allow the service-worker to work on caching them while responding to the fetch event.

  ```js
  async function fetchLocalOrRemote (request: Request) {
    try {
        const url = request.url.replace(location.origin, 'https://local.example.com')
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            headers: new Headers(request.headers),
        })
        if (response.ok) {
            return response
        }
    } catch { }
    return fetch(request)
  }

  async function fetchFromServer (event: FetchEvent, request: Request) {
    const response = await fetchLocalOrRemote(request)
    if (response.status === 206) {
        response.clone()
            .arrayBuffer()
            .then((buffer) => {
                // do something unrelated to cache the response
            })
    } else if (response.status === 200) {
        const cacheResponse = response.clone()
        // do something unrelated to cache the response
    }
    return response
  }

  async function fetchFromCache (event: FetchEvent, request: Request) {
    const response = await caches.match(event.request.url, {
        ignoreVary: true,
        ignoreSearch: true,
        cacheName: CACHES.media,
    })
    if (!response) {
        return fetchFromServer(event, request)
    }
    // something unrelated to respond from cache
  }

  function onFetch (event: FetchEvent) {
    const request = event.request
    if (request.method === "GET") {
        const url = new URL(request.url)
        if (url.pathname.startsWith("/api/file")) {
            event.respondWith(fetchFromCache(event, request))
        }
    }
  }

  self.addEventListener("fetch", onFetch)
  ```

##### Can some explain why the audio playback gets interrupted when it started playing as a stream of 206 responses from an origin, and in the middle of streaming, starts receiving 206 responses from another origin ?

The response header received by the audio element are identical, whether it's from `local.example.com` or from `example.com`:

```yaml
Request URL: https://example.com/api/file/clh2jwi0s030kyqjx2i45ct6w
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 206  (from service worker)
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

accept-ch: Sec-CH-DPR, Sec-CH-Viewport-Width, Downlink
access-control-allow-origin: https://example.com
access-control-expose-headers: Content-Range
cache-control: public, max-age=31536000
Content-Length: 524288
Content-Range: bytes 3145728-3670015/6044646
content-type: audio/MPEG
date: Thu, 04 May 2023 14:15:14 GMT
server: Apache
service-worker-allowed: /
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that for the `<audio>` to be able to receive chunks from multiple origins when requesting a single source, you need to give it the [`crossorigin` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#crossorigin).